# Monte Carlo March Madness Simulation

Tags: python

for class I need to model predictions for the March Madness bracket... and I decided to go through Python rather than Excel. My approach is, basically, to generate x amount of random numbers, that x being each team's respective shots per game, and if that number is greater than y, which would be that respective team's shooting percentage, they would miss that shot. By doing so, scores of games and outcomes can be VERY roughly predicted. I am very new to Python but this is what I know:

```
import random

for i in range(25):
   print(random.random())
```

This gives me 25 random numbers, but now I have to compare these to the shooting percentage to each team. How do I compare all 25 of these random numbers to determine whether each is less than, say, 0.400... and count up the ones that are?

Answer (score 1):

You could write

```
import random

sum = 0
boundary = 0.4
n = 25

for i in range(n):
    random_num = random.random()
    if random_num < boundary:
        sum += random_num

print(sum)
```

So that prints the sum of all the number, but might I add that 25 samples will be far too little for a Monte Carlo simulation. I made a program once for class and we user 10.000.000 samples, so I added the variable n that you can easily change.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum`

```
import random

p = .4
n = 25
above_p = sum(1 for _ in range(n) if random.random() > p)
# or sum(random.random() > p for _ in range(n))
```